# How to shrink static cells width in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I want to do something like:[image]

I am able to do that with dynamic cells, but can't figure it out with static cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I subclassed my UITableViewCell, and over-wrote the layoutSubviews method in my subclass:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x,
                             self.bounds.origin.y,
                             self.bounds.size.width/3,
                             self.bounds.size.height);

    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```